# How to debug "HTTP request sent, awaiting response"?

Tags: linux, networking, http, wireshark, debugging

I have a Linux server on an ADSL connection, and I just noticed that sometimes I get

```
Connecting to example.com|xxx.xxx.xxx.122|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
```

when I use `wget` or e.g. a browser like firefox.

In the case of `wget` pressing CTRL-C and then try again "solves the problem", and in the case of firefox, reloading the page also makes the page load.

It seams to be random when it happens. I have tried to change the DNS to Google's DNS, but I still get the same problems there.

**Question**

How do I debug something like that, so I can find the source of the problem or perhaps a pattern?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have you ever tried waiting to see what HTTP status code returns?

To debug this case, open 2 terminals: in the first, ssh to your server and type:

```
# tcpdump -vv -s0 tcp port 80 -w /tmp/example.pcap
```

*(you can also append `and src host <client_IP>` to filter junk requests)*

and in the second, use `wget` to browse your website, reproduce this problem and switch to the first terminal and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Copy this `.pcap` file to the client and open with Wireshark to see what happens.

Comment: This should be interesting! I haven't tried to let it time out. How long would that take for it to timeout? 10 minutes? 1 hour?

Answer (score 3):

If you see:

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response...
```

This means that the DNS works fine, that the TCP connection is in established state and the request was send. I think that the cause of your problems is the remote server that might be busy.

As @quanta said a network capture will give you better details. In Wireshark just use Follow TCP Stream to see the HTTP conversation. Pay attention to ICMP messages too.

Answer (score 0):

Restart your Apache Server. This should solve the problem.

Comment: Sounds like Windows. If in doubt, try Alt-Ctl-Delete.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue on a **freshly provisioned** AWS instance:

`apt install` would fail, claiming that it couldn't fetch some package. When I tried to fetch the package manually with `wget`, it would sometimes hang indefinitely, and sometimes succeed immediately (after it hanged indefinitely).

Restarting the server didn't help. Then I terminated and reprovisioned the instance, after which I didn't have the problem on the new instance.

Go figure.